# Favoriting Items in Flutter Using Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I want to be able to favorite/mark items in a already populated local sqlite database to display on a "favorites page" that shows a list of favorited items.

In this sqlite database, I have a table of genres and a table of books relating to a specific genre. I am not using a model "book" class to display book information in a list. I have using a rawQuery to place a ROW of book information into a List to display that book information in a bookView page. Like so..

```
Future getDescriptionData() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "asset_sample_sqlite.db");
    ByteData data =
        await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "sample_sqlite.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    Database db = await openDatabase(path);
    await db
        .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = "${widget.id}"') // id passed on from previous page where it shows a list of books
        .then((results) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
        initialized = true;
        bookDescription = results;
      });
```

then I display the information like so..

```
body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: !loading
                    ? new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: bookDescription.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Card(
                              elevation: 2.0,
                              child: new ListTile(
                                title: new Text(${bookDescription[index]['title']}",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                subtitle: new Text(
                                  "${bookDescription[index]['summary']}",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
```

What is the best method to include an iconButton in this card, and then have an option to favorite this "book" to add it to a shortlist of books that are favorited in a different favorite book list page?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Favorites` table that only holds `id` values of the `books` table that have been favored. You should read that table also in `getDescriptionData` (or a similar `getFavoriteData` method) so that you have  a list of favored book ids in memory, available when the `build` function is called.  In the `Card` add a `leading` argument with an `Icon` representing a filled or unfilled star (depending on whether the `bookDescription[index]['id']` is in the favored list) and wrap it in a `GestureDetector` where in its `onTap` you add or remove the book `id` from the list in memory *and* in your SQL table, then call `setState` to rebuild the list with the new favorite information.